# How do I zip a folder in JupyterLab?

Tags: python, jupyter-lab

I have a folder named myfolder (with multiple files) in JupyterLab. I can download files but not folders as JupyterLab does not allow it. I, therefore, want to zip the folder then download it to my desktop.

Question: how do I zip myfolder?

This one didn't work: [Downloads folder from JupyterLab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61710897/downloads-folder-from-jupyterlab)

Comment: Does your jupyterlab come with a [Terminal](https://imgur.com/wNPVNwb.png)? If so, what is the output when you type `zip` command into the terminal and press enter on your keyboard?

Answer (score 6):

Did you try `tar` instead of `zip` as well?

Check the discussion in [github](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/3092)

> on my notebook zip is not working but tar is. so
>
> `%%bash`
>
> `tar -czf archive.tar.gz foldername`